# Cancel webclient Async request

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, webclient, windows-phone-7.1

Hopefully an easy question for you all but I'm really struggling.
I've only recently started programming and have just had an app certified to the WP7 app store but noticed a bug myself that i would like to fix before making the app public.

Basically I have a search box where the user enters a chemical name and a webservice returns an image and its molecular weight. What i would like to do is cancel the webclient if the user navigates away from the page before the download is completed or if a new search is made before the previous is completed (this currently crashes the app as I believe you can only have one request at a time??)

```
private void searchCactus()
        {

            WebClient imgClient = new WebClient();
            imgClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(imgClient_OpenReadCompleted);

            WebClient mwClient = new WebClient();
            mwClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(mwClient_DownloadStringCompleted);

           if (DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No network found, please check network availability and try again");
            }
            else if (compoundSearchBox.Text.Contains("?"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("\"?\" Not Permitted");
                    return;
                }
            else if (compoundSearchBox.Text != "")

                {

                    progBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;

                    string imageuri = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + compoundSearchBox.Text + "/image?format=png&width=300&height=300";
                    string mwURI = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + compoundSearchBox.Text + "/mw";

                    imgClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@imageuri), imgClient);



                 mwClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@mwURI), mwClient);

 // //lower keyboard   
                this.Focus();

                }
                else MessageBox.Show("Enter Search Query");

        }
```

I tried implementing the following button but it does not work

```
private void buttonCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imgClient.CancelAsync();
        mwClient.CancelAsync();
    }
```

as "the name 'mwClient' does not exist in the current context"

I would be very grateful if anybody could provide some guidance

Comment: Just put the two clients into fields in your class.

Comment: @svick thanks that was easier than i expected, just to clarify i added   public partial class MWSearch : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private WebClient imgClient;
        private WebClient mwClient; ......    was that what you meant? many thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the two clients into fields in your class.

Comment: The shortest answer I ever saw here